# Youtube streaming media

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am working on a ASP platform [and bespoke CMS] using streaming media to show youtube clips.

I need to make them responsive but don't seem to be able to.

Is there a fix in the JavaScript?

I can't use the HTML because it needs to be generic as I have a large number of streaming videos.

```
<div id="AssetImgHolder" class="clear" style="width:560px;">
<div class="asset">
<div id="div85089">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//<![CDATA[
        jwplayer('div85089').setup({
        id: 'jw85089',
        file: 'my youtube url',
        width: 560,
        height: 315,
        autostart: 'false',
        repeat: 'false',
        controlbar: 'bottom'
        });
        jwplayer('div85089').onError( function(event){
        this.controls.display.setText('HTML5 support for MP4 video only works with H.264 encoded video.');
        });

//]]>-->
</script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('div85089').onPlay(function(){ 
        TrackMediaPlayEvent('162059', 'video (English) - with John Smith', null);
        });
        jwplayer('div85089').onPause(function(){ 
        TrackMediaPauseEvent('162059', 'video (English) - with John Smith ', null);
        });
        jwplayer('div85089').onComplete(function(){ 
        TrackMediaCompleteEvent('162059', 'video (English) - with John Smith', null);
        });
        </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the JWPlayer responsive, set a desired aspect ratio (16:9 is the standard these days) and set width and height to percentage instead of specifying absolute values in the JWPlayer object.

> **width**
>
> Width of the player. Defaults to 480 pixels. We recommend setting this to at least 320 pixels, since otherwise certain UI elements may
>   not fit. It can also be set to "100%" to enable responsive design, in
>   combination with the aspectratio option.

Having said that for height 180px is recommended at least for controls and images to display correctly.

Check out the config-ref guide for tonnes of other option that might come in handy.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference